# Mod 2 Totaro spectral sequence for non-orientable manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I've been reading Burt Totaro's article ["Configuration spaces of algebraic varieties"](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/config.pdf), and I have a question regarding the main theorem (Theorem 1 in page 3 of the pdf). The theorem in question gives the description of a spectral sequence converging to $H^*(F(X,n);k)$ where $k$ is a field and $X$ is an orientable manifold. My question is:

Is it known if orientability for the manifold is necessary for the case $k=\mathbb{Z}/2$? If the manifold is non-orientable, it would still be $\mathbb{Z}/2$-orientable, so perhaps the argument can be adjusted (I haven't tried this yet, I figured that perhaps someone has done it already).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be fine. Orientability is used to show that the locally constant sheaves $R^i f_\ast \mathbf Z$ occuring in the Leray spectral sequence are actually constant along the diagonals of $X^n$, where $f \colon F(X,n) \hookrightarrow X^n$ is the inclusion. This is true mod 2 without the orientability assumption.

Note also that the generators $G_{ij}$ in Totaro's results come from the locally euclidean structure on $X$. You therefore need to observe that $H^\bullet(F(\mathbf R^m,n),\mathbf Z)$ is torsion free, so that $H^\bullet(F(\mathbf R^m,n),\mathbf Z/2) \cong H^\bullet(F(\mathbf R^m,n),\mathbf Z) \otimes \mathbf Z/2$, in order to carry out the same local calculation Totaro makes also in the mod 2 case.

Comment: I see. I will follow the proof and check the details then. Thanks!